# How to get an LG Ultra HD (27UD88) and Macbook Pro 13" 2017 running at 60hz?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, 4k

I recently bought a **MacBook Pro 13-inch 2017** and an **LG Ultra HD (27UD88) 27"** display.
Before buying the display I researched a bit and found no issues in relation to the MacBook Pro.

However, after attaching the screen via the USB-C cable that came along with the display, I only have the option of a 30hz refresh rate.

I've Googled this without finding much - it seems like no one else is having this problem. From a result, I've also learned that my "Display" page in "System Preferences" looks slightly different than a screenshot from an article.

- http://www.lg.com/us/monitors/lg-27UD88-W-4k-uhd-led-monitor (LG official page, shows 60hz)
- https://9to5mac.com/2016/06/04/how-to-enable-4k-60hz-resolution-2016-macbook/ (speaks of a patch needed for MacBook 2016)
- https://www.reddit.com/r/apple/comments/5azoij/2016_macbook_pros_and_lg_27ud88/ (at least one use confirms 60hz with MacBook Pro)

Comment: Why change the tag from 4K to 5K? This LG monitor is 4K. 3840p.

Comment: I think you're right. I was tricked by this in the system report: https://imgur.com/euIRJxB. Do you have an idea why it shows like so?

Comment: Weird. If you screenshot the whole screen (shift Command 3), what's the dimensions on the .png?

Comment: According to "get info": 5120 × 2880. From the "Displays" tab: https://imgur.com/3nZLfLs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working. I'm not sure exactly how, but here's what I tried, in the order of what I believe fixed it:

1. Enable DisplayPort 1.2 in screen configuration
2. Reverse the USB-C cable
3. Set "Ratio" to "1:1" in screen configuration (I've since tested this and switching it back had no negative effect)

(3) was recommended by a user in a forum thread.

#### Update 2018-01-29

I've since experienced the problem once more, without changing any settings. Attaching/detaching the cable fixed it.

#### Update 2018-05-06

After the most recent MacOS update (`10.13.4`) it no longer downgrades to 30hz, instead, it never comes on. If the cable is dettached, the computer crashes and has to be booted. So far, the only solution I know of is restarting the computer, which works 50 % of the time, and if not, reattach the cable (it usually won't crash after a restart).

This happens after screen sleep and detaching/attaching.

#### Update 2018-12-13

In this third evolution of the problem (MacOS `10.14.1`) the computer no longer crashes. Roughly 9/10 times it will display in 30hz/horrible resolution and all I have to do (sigh) is detach/attach the cable until I hit that 1/10 where it works. It's a daily 5 minutes routine for me.

**This setup (MacBook Pro 13" 2017 w/o touch + 27UD88-W) is not recommendable to anyone.**

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with any HDMI cable. My solution was: MacBookPro 2017 thunderbolt out > thunderbolt in on a hub > Display Port cable out from hub > Display Port cable into back of LG monitor. Looks beautiful. And when I bring up Apple's display system prefs, the LG shows the same window with 5 scaling options that appears on laptop itself. Refresh rate not displayed but it's smooth and fast.

Comment: Does the hub charge the computer as well? If so, which hub specifically do you have?